# How to run Ember.js on localhost?

Tags: ruby, ember.js

I have written a simple Ember code which is accessing a REST Service. As I am new to Ember I am not aware of how to run it on localhost.

Comment: Have you seen the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/), [Ember101](http://ember101.com/) or [EmberWatch](http://emberwatch.com/)? can you please edit your question with details of the steps you've taken so far and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a webserver which you can run locally on your machine. If that is what you mean else please provide more detail to your question.

For example:

- [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/)
- [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/)
- and so on...

Comment: i tried it on apache but it was not working as my skype was using the port 80 which is used by apche so after disablling that in  skype it worked for me then i It worked with both Apcahe and tomcat. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Ember is a client side framework, it doesn't run on a server, it gets served to a client (browser) and runs on it. You can use any web server for this purpose (apache, nginx...).

If you just want to play with it you can create an index.html file where you include ember and your javascript files and open it with a browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [serve](http://get-serve.com/) Ruby Gem

`gem install serve`

From the root of your ember app

`serve`

In your browser navigate to

`http://localhost:4000/`